# XSD Schemas - Enumeration based on value in document

Tags: xml, enums, xsd

This is a right long shot.

If I have a defined element in my XSD, containing two attributes, say NAME and VALUE, is it possible to restrict the VALUE enumeration based on the value in the Name?

For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ConfigDef">
    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The name of this Config setting.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>           
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="VALUE" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The value of this Config setting.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I don't think it can be done.  Can it be done?  Is there XSD hacks to get it to work?

Comment: Could you add details about how you are implementing your XSD validation?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with embedded schematron

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:complexType name="ConfigDef">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:appinfo>
        <sch:pattern name="Test constraints on the ConfigDef element"
          xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
          <sch:rule
            context="ConfigDef">
            <sch:assert test="@NAME eq 'foo' and @VALUE = ('bar','baz')">Error message when the assertion condition is broken...</sch:assert>
            <sch:assert test="@NAME eq 'qux' and @VALUE = ('teh','xyz')">Error message when the assertion condition is broken...</sch:assert>
          </sch:rule>
        </sch:pattern>
      </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" type="xsd:string">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>The name of this Config setting.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>           
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="VALUE" type="xsd:string">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>The value of this Config setting.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Or you could do this with a Relax Schema

```
element ConfigDef {
  ((
  attribute NAME {'foo'},
  attribute VALUE {'bar'|'baz'}) |  
  (
  attribute NAME {'qux'},
  attribute VALUE {'teh'|'xyz'}))
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? That's a pretty broad question.

Comment: For instance, does .NET support it? Java? PHP?

Comment: According to google: http://relaxng.org/#validators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468554.aspx#schematron_topic4 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema_language_comparison#Tool_Support_4

Comment: Did you notice that the MSDN article was from 2004 and referred to a free implementation whose latest version is also 2004? I think the bottom line is that this is not a solution for most of us who need to validate XML.