# Can an XML schema be specific by attribute value?

Tags: xsd

If I have the following XML:

```
    <variables>
        <variable name="age">92</variable>
        <variable name="school">Fairview</variable>
        <variable name="birthdate">11/13/2012</variable>
    </variables>
```

Is there a way to create a schema where, based on the name attribute value, it then defines the node value (as decimal, string, date)? If so, how?

**Update:** This is for code in C# so I need to get this schema info using the >NET runtime.

thanks - dave

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308585/xsd-schemas-enumeration-based-on-value-in-document/13313354#13313354, this could be done with embedded schematron (which is implemented in XSLT [here](http://code.google.com/p/schematron/) or in RelaxNG as long as the XSD datatypes are sufficient for your needs http://www.relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2814737

Answer (score 0):

Here's a schema for your example in Relax NG

```
datatypes xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes"

element variable {
  ((
  attribute name {'age'},
  xsd:int) |  
  (
  attribute name {'school'},
  text) |  
  (
  attribute name {'birthdate'},
  xsd:date))
}
```