# XML Schema (XSD 1.1) Dynamic enumeration depending on other attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I have a rather simple XML structure;

```
<list... >
    <members>
        <person type="NAME_WITH_A">
            <name>Ada</name>
        </person>
        <person type="NAME_WITH_B">
            <name>Berta</name>
        </person>
    </members> 
</list>
```

I want to restrict the value of 'name' to a certain set of names, depending on the value of the attribute 'type' of element 'person'.

So, for example, if `<person type="NAME_WITH_A">`, only the names

- Anna
- Ada
- Amanda

should be valid as ,
if `<person type="NAME_WITH_B">`, only

- Berta,
- Bob
- Bret

should be valid values for the `<name>` element.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653995/dynamic-enumeration-restriction-using-xsd-1-1) i created the following Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="list">
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="NAME_WITH_A"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NAME_WITH_B"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="name">
    <xs:alternative test="@type='NAME_WITH_A'" type="choice_names_A"/>
    <xs:alternative test="@type='NAME_WITH_B'" type="choice_names_B"/>  
    <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="members">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="person" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="choice_names_A">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Anna"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Ada"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Amanda"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="choice_names_B">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Berta"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Bob"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Bret"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

which does not really work for me. I have the feeling, that, as I refer in `test="@type='NAME_WITH_A'"` to the @type attribute of ANOTHER element, it is always false.

I also tried `test="list / members / person / @type='NAME_WITH_A'"` but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea in using Conditional Type Assignment, but you're applying it to the wrong element.  Instead of applying it to `name`, you have to apply it to `person` (the element whose type will vary according to the `type` attribute).  From there, you can vary the content model of `person` to have `name` elements of differing types.

See also **[How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878402/how-to-make-type-depend-on-attribute-value-using-conditional-type-assignment)**.